# XML, XSL transformation with arrays

Tags: xml, xslt

Iam struggling with XML/XSL transformation.
I have an XML file (**F2.xml**) that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "F2.xsl"?> 

<StateProfile>
<StateName xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <a:string>New York</a:string>
      <a:string>Maryland,Delaware</a:string>
      <a:string>Vermont</a:string>
      <a:string>Maine</a:string>
    </StateName>
    <Heading1>
      <Heading2>
        <Name>States Overview</Name>
        </Heading2>
    </Heading1>
       <StateCode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <a:string>41</a:string>
      <a:string>1</a:string>
      <a:string>21</a:string>
      <a:string>33</a:string>
    </StateCode>
</StateProfile>
```

Below is **F2.xsl**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
version="1.0"  
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match = "/StateProfile">    
            <xsl:for-each select = "StateName"> 
             <xsl:value-of select = "a:string"/>  
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
            <xsl:for-each select = "Heading1/Heading2"> 
            <xsl:value-of select = "Name"/>  
            </xsl:for-each> 
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
            <xsl:for-each select = "StateCode"> 
                <xsl:value-of select = "a:string"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
             <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 

</xsl:template>
```

The output I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
New York
States Overview
41
```

I am unable to print all the elements in the array. How can I do it. I use Notepad++ with XML tools plugin.

Thanks

Comment: You should be looping on the `a:string`, not the `StateName`. The way you've written it, you loop on `StateName` and display the first element `a:string`. You should either have a seperate template for `StateName`, which contains the loop for the `a:string` elements, or loop over `StateName/a:string` and use `value-of '.'`.

Comment: Thanks so much that works. Can you please suggest tutorial for learning XML/XSL transformation? I am struggling every single step of the way.I am able to see this in NotePad correctly formatted but not in IE11 browser. I added <html><body> tag also.

Comment: You can check out the one on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/). It's basic but good starting point. I don't have any other beyond that.